# sql server collation for stored procedures generated script

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, collation

I have generated the stored procedures script for a database which is "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS". I run that script without problem in one server which has "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" collation, but in another server which has "Modern_Spanish_BIN" collation, the script fails because some variables are declared @userLogin (or something else) and they are used @userlogin. CAPS vs no caps

There is no difference whether script is like:

`EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'my sp body'`

or script is like:

`CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].MySpName`

I have executed the following to ensure the database collation is the correct one:

`SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDatabase','collation');/*returns "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS"*/`

I'm not allowed to change server collation.

What could I do (other than change the case of the thousands of expressions) in order to succesfully run the script and ensure the sp's will work fine??? And, will there be an impact at runtime when a sp try to compare varchar values???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must change the case of the thousands of expressions, learn your lesson, and in future always test your code in case sensitive collation servers.

Comment: A decent text editor should help you Find/Replace, even for case differences